# Regular expression for validating file input string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have an text file with below input, I need to validate the input in ruby whether it is correct format or not?

Need to read an each line of text file and validate that whether the input is matching to **Integer,s1-integer,s2-integer,s3-integer,s4-integer** format other wise I need to raise an error that file input format is mismatch.

The input line is not limited to 5, it can be any number of lines.

**Integer,s1-integer,s2-integer,s3-integer,s4-integer**

Example inputs:

```
1,S1­-88,S2­-53,S3­-69,S4­-64 
2,S1­-92,S2­-86,S3­-93,S4­-77 
3,S1­-53,S2­-59,S3­-72,S4­-59 
4,S1­-60,S2­-52,S3­-85,S4­-62 
5,S1­-85,S2­-53,S3­-74,S4­-61
```

Comment: What is the invalid input?

Comment: @Rajagopalan If I have add one more line with some unwanted line or giving wrong format input(format of input must be 5,S1­-85,S2­-53,S3­-74,S4­-61 )

Comment: So input equal to 5 lines and S1, S2, S3, S4 only and always present and related value as integer?

Comment: Dude please be clear about what you want, otherwise your question is going to receive so many downvotes

Comment: Its still unclear, @NatarajaB Do you just want to validate whether there are S1,S2,S3,S4 followed by an integer? Is your validation for an integer? We can't guess what you want, you need to be clear about it.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla I want first should be integer, s1-with integervalue,s2-integer value,s3-integer value, s4-integer value.

Comment: @iGian, Its not limited to 5, it could be any number of lines

Comment: @Rajagopalan I have updated my question

Comment: Thats clear now, i removed my down vote!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you need to validate the following input:

- a number followed by four elements with a format `,S1­-85`

The following pattern matches the input of that type:

```
\d(\,S\d\-\d\d){4}
```

- `\d` matches a number
- `(\,S\d\-\d\d)` matches a group of type `,S1­-85`
- `{4}` tells to match `,S1­-85` group 4 times

Comment: So we need to guess what's actually the question is, eh?